# NullPointer trying to find resource

Tags: java, android, xml, replace, nullpointerexception

I am taking a look at this [Search field](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview)

I am trying to create the searchbar, but I get an eror everytime shown below:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View com.arlib.floatingsearchview.FloatingSearchView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

**Here is my XML file search.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/parent_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<View
    android:id="@+id/header_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/sliding_search_view_header_height"
    android:background="#01579B"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/dim_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.arlib.floatingsearchview.FloatingSearchView
        android:id="@+id/floating_search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:translationY="@dimen/sliding_search_view_header_height"
        app:floatingSearch_close_search_on_keyboard_dismiss="false"
        app:floatingSearch_dimBackground="false"
        app:floatingSearch_dismissOnOutsideTouch="true"
        app:floatingSearch_leftActionMode="showHamburger"
        app:floatingSearch_menu="@menu/menu_search_view"
        app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginLeft="@dimen/search_view_inset"
        app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginRight="@dimen/search_view_inset"
        app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginTop="@dimen/search_view_inset"
        app:floatingSearch_searchHint="Search..."
        app:floatingSearch_showSearchKey="true"
        app:floatingSearch_suggestionsListAnimDuration="250"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

and here is what I did in the activity class:

```
public class CreateSearch extends AppCompatActivity{

FloatingSearchView mSearchView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search.xml);

    mSearchView.findViewById(R.id.floating_search_view);
 ...
```

I get the error here

```
mSearchView.findViewById(R.id.floating_search_view);
```

any idea why? any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mSearchView` is not initialised yet so has the default value `null`. Try changing to

`mSearchView = (FloatingSearchView) findViewById(R.id.floating_search_view);`

Comment: have you tried replacing the offending line with the one in the answer? mSearchView is null when you try to initialise, so you cannot invoke any of its methods, right? you're trying to do `null.findViewById(resId);` , which won't work

Comment: "Also, findViewById(int res) is a method belong to Activity class not FloatingSearchView class." If this were true, then the code would not compile. There would be no NPE since the app wouldn't even run. Note that `View` also has [`findViewById()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)). With that said, using the version of `findViewById()` from `Activity` is much more common than using the one from `View`.